# CollapsingToolbarLayout with a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-design-library, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to use the CollapsingToolbarLayout to have a collapsible toolbar with a ViewPager that fades away while scrolling up but I seem to lose the ability to scroll up if the ViewPager is present.

The ViewPager is supposed to show multiple images in the Toolbar.

Here's the XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- Content -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: xml looks okay what problem you are facing?

Comment: @MukeshRana I'm able to scroll horizontally in the ViewPager but not vertically to hide it.

Comment: but you should have some scrollable view below your viewpager, like in your case it is NestedScrollView. so you have to scroll vertically your NestedScrollView not the viewpager. Viewpager is simply reacting to that scroll effect

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. Could you show an example? I'm trying to a create a layout with a collapsible image slider in the toolbar. Are you saying that I need a NestedScrollView instead of a View Pager?

Comment: I have the same problem, if I don't specify a height it doesn't show up. But I can't specify it because it's an image and the height is based on the width. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to fix this by setting the ViewPager's height to a fixed size. It seems that `wrap_content` doesn't regardless of the image size.

Comment: In my case I included a fragment instead of a ViewPager, and for this I can set height to "wrap_content". The main difference in my implementation compared to yours is, that fitSystemWindows is not set and has the default value.