# How to put slider in a collapsing layout on Android?

Tags: android, slider, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to put a slider between the toolbar and the tab layout in a collapsing toolbar, Like the one in [tv showtime app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ1jd.jpg).  I tried to replace the ImageView with an ViewPager + 2 fragments but it doesn't work. [collapsing toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L0js.png) Is there any other solution?

**tv showtime app**

[image]

**collapsing toolbar**

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/rootlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleMarginTop="15dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent" >

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

slides.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/slide1"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try adding the tab layout right below the collapsing action bar?

Comment: It is not what I want to do, I want to insert a slider left/right in the collapsing toolbar

Comment: Look at this approach - http://stackoverflow.com/q/32666276

Comment: Thank you, but i found another way to create a slider using imageSwitcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can just put an ImageSwitcher instead of ImageView, and then programatically change images 
https://danielme.com/tip-android-31-image-slider-con-imageswitcher/