# Viewpager within a Collapsing toolbar synced with bottom layout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-design-library, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want a **ViewPager** in **CollapsingToolbar** which scroll flags will be **scroll** and **enterAlways**, but the problem is the **ListView** within a nestedscrollview below the **AppBarLayout** is not expanded to the bottom so I cannot see the full **ListView** but a single item.

[check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCMpd.jpg)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="230dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/indicator"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- Content -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvCheck"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666276/collapsingtoolbarlayout-with-a-viewpager) approach

Answer (score 0):

For the CoordinatorLayout to work properly you need the scrolling child to implement [NestedScrollingChild](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html). Such classes are `NestedScrollView` and RecyclerView.

To say it short - just use a `RecyclerView` for your scrolling content and it'll work correctly :)